# How to see RabbitMQ messages

Tags: rabbitmq, rmq

Can't view rabbitmq queue messages after using the get messages command.

```
rabbitmqadmin get queue='queue_name' -H localhost -P 15672 -u rmq -p rmq --vhost=/ count=100
```

Queue count shows 100 messages, cant use the above command again to see the messages.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to read https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html to understand how rabbitmq works.

The command `get` [consumes](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#basics) the messages so you can't consume them anymore.

If you want to consume the same messages multi-times you can use the [stream](https://www.rabbitmq.com/streams.html) queue type.

Comment: I read the messages using rabbitmqadmin get command. I can still see the same total messages in the queue. It transitioned from acknowledged to unacknowledged. And now i can't read the message using the same command. Is there a way to read unack messages?

Answer (score 1):

When rabbitMq consumer consumes a mensagem from a queue the same will be deleted from the queue. If you just want to see the message you can log to the RabbitMQ Managment and read the messages, if they're not serialized. But if you want to consume the same message for some reason multiple times read the part of streams queue on the documentation.

Comment: I read the messages using rabbitmqadmin get command. I can still see the same total messages in the queue. It transitioned from acknowledged to unacknowledged. And now i can't read the message using the same command.